# On debugging its shows 'Connection refused' [ASP.NET]

Tags: asp.net

When LoginPage.aspx loads on the browser, it displays **'Connection refused'**. Some issue with TCP/IP? Help me with the fix.

> //localhost:1537/WebSite2/LoginPage.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this issue is due to the firewall client is not installed on your computer.
Try installing firewall client software e.g. **ISA Client**.I hope this will resolve your issue.

Comment: ok..Plz download ISA Client from this link..http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10193